# Nativescript/Angular - Print in bluetooth mini printer

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

My app needs to be connected to a mini printer in bluetooth way. When I work with html I only need hide elements and call some print function in the browser. How can I achieve this in nativescript?

Comment: Did you try [nativescript-printer](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-printer)?

Comment: Great. Work very well. Thanks.